# concatenation between string and i

Tags: matlab

I have two cells:

```
table1 = cell(1,1);
table2 = cell(1,1);

table1{1}(:,1) = [1 2 3];
table1{1}(:,2) = [4 5 6];
table2{1}(:,1) = [3 6 5];
table2{1}(:,2) = [4 9 7];
```

**>>table1{1}**

ans =

```
 1     4
 2     5
 3     6
```

**>> table2{1}**

ans =

```
 3     4
 6     9
 5     7
```

What I want is two compute the sum of all the columns of each table. For example, `for table1`:

`sum (column1 , column2) = result_column.`

By the way I wrote the code below:

```
table_list = cell(2, 1);
for i=1:2
    table_list{i} = strcat('table', num2str(i)); % table_list{1}='table1', table_list{2} ='table3'
end

sum = zeros(3,1);

for i=1:2
    x = table_list{i};
    for j=1:2
        sum = sum + x{1}(:, j) % here I got always the error below
    end
end
```

**What is my problem:**

I always get the error

```
??? Cell contents reference from a non-cell array
object.
```

So I don't know how to concatenate 'table' with 'i' in order to get table1{1}(...) and table2{1}(...).

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: `sum(table1{1},1)` and `sum(table2{1},1)`?

Comment: Well, `x` is clearly a string, not a cell array. Why not just put the matrices directly in a 2x1 cell array and save mucking about with variable names at all?

Comment: @Notlikethat great I will try your idea :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concatenation is ok, you just need to use function "eval" to execute the string as a MATLAB expression. 
Just replace `x = table_list{i};` with `x=eval(table_list{i});` and you can access the cell.

I wouldn't use "sum" as the name of the variable since it is a Matlab function. You can compute the sum of the columns using `sum(x{1}(:, j))` (after removing the line `sum = zeros(3,1);`).